# Tensorflow is not installed properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, tensorflow

I am a beginner and I tried installing tensor flow on Macbook according to the instructions given on the site.

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo easy_install --upgrade six
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

After installation , when I am trying to import tensor flow , I am getting the following error:

```
    >>> import tensorflow
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import versions
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/versions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
>>>
```

I am new to python and I have tried a few solutions on internet but none of them have worked so far. Perhaps the error is due to the pip installation. I am stuck on this since 2 days. Thanks for help!

Comment: Tried `sudo pip install -U numpy`?

Comment: Yeah , it shows                                                                                  Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pip install numpy==1.10.4` to get the latest version? There is also a flag to pip, `--upgrade` which may help.

Comment: Nope. I tried it but it's still showing the same Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages –

Comment: Can you try installing all that only using `pip` in a `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 2):

To add onto the previous answer - on my `OSX` machine (10.11), I found two factory installations of `numpy` - one in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy` and the other in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/`.  As far as I can tell, pip will upgrade the one in /Library, but python kept trying to use the one in /System/Library/ first.

As a temporary solution, I just renamed the `numpy` folder in `/System/Library` to `numpy.old`.  `Tensorflow` imported correctly after that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I came across the same problem. This was caused by an earlier version of factory-included numpy that on the factory-installed Python on Max OSX.

I tried `sudo pip uninstall numpy` and the factor-included numpy still exists. To solve this problem, I upgraded the factory-included numpy using `easy_install`, then used `pip` to install `tensorflow` and it worked:

```
sudo easy_install -U numpy
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

So Finally what I did was removed tensorflow ,pip and everything. The problem was that I was using Mac OSX python due to which I was having the problem. I used homebrew to install python, then created virtualenv and used pip to install tensorflow again. After that it was working.

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

This resolved my issue:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
```

## Details

**Environment and symptoms**

I have a 3 pythons installed on my Mac OS X Yosemite:

- 2.6 which came with OS
- 2.7 which I have installed
- 3.4 which I have installed

Of course I did a poor job at setting things properly and the python binaries and libs are all over the place on the mac.

I got this error when attempting to work with https://github.com/Ning-Ding/Implementation-CVPR2015-CNN-for-ReID/tree/master/CUHK03

```
$ python ./main.py --dataset cuhk-03.h5

Using TensorFlow backend.
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 14, in <module>
    from model import generate_model,compile_model
  File "/Users/rv186016/repositories/Implementation-CVPR2015-CNN-for-ReID/CUHK03/model.py", line 12, in <module>
    from keras.layers import Input
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/activations.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import backend as K
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

**Solution**

After looking at ***se7en007***'s comment on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/559, I ran these commands which loved my issue. See the diff in the `numpy` version and path before and after the `rm` command.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.8.0rc1'
>>> numpy.__path__
['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy']
>>> exit()

$ sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
MUSRV186016-382:CUHK03 rv186016$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__path__
['/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy']
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.12.0'
>>> ^D

$ python ./main.py --dataset cuhk-03.h5
Using TensorFlow backend.
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 160, 60, 3)    0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)             (None, 160, 60, 3)    0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 156, 56, 20)   1520        input_1[0][0]
                                                                   input_2[0][0]
...
```