# Import tensorflow error on mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

**Enviorment**:

Mac OSX 10.10

Python: 2.7.10

I have following error when I was trying to `import tensorflow`

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I was following the [official install pege](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#pip-installation), and typed these two command

```
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl

$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

I've tried uninstall `tensorflow` and `protobuf`,and then reinstall `tensorflow`, but it threw the same error.

### Update

After I uninstall `numpy`and`tensorflow`, I reinstall `numpy`.However, I couldn't reinstall `tensorflow`.

It threw this

```
$sudo  pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
The directory '/Users/Coda/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/Coda/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

Is that because I uninstall `tensorflow` wrongly?
I use `pip uninstall tensorflow` to uninstall.

Comment: What happens when you try to `import numpy`?

Comment: I can import `numpy` perfectly.

Comment: You might be using the wrong version of TensorFlow.

Comment: I'm not sure which version I need to install, but I install `tensorflow 0.9.0`

Comment: Finally, I installed `virtualenv`, and it worked. But I still want to figure this problem out.

Comment: I think the issue is that your `numpy` is one version older than needed (`0x9` = 9; `0xa` = 10). Maybe upgrade numpy and see if the tensorflow import works after that.

Comment: For your new error, try the pip install with the `--no-cache-dir` option.

Comment: refer to the solution in another thread, I've got mine fixed.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750543/tensorflow-is-not-installed-properly/38225761#38225761

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that your `numpy` is one version older than needed (`0x9` = 9; `0xa` = 10). Maybe upgrade numpy and see if importing `tensorflow` works after that.

*Edit/Update:* For your new error, try the pip install with the `--no-cache-dir` option.

Comment: Thanks, but I encountered new trouble, I've updated question.

Comment: I did, and it can install fine, but I still can't import `tensorflow`, it threw the same error, and  my `numpy`'s version now is `1.8.0rc1`

Comment: Did anyone solve this issue? I really need help resolving this too! Thanks!

Comment: I installed the regular tensorflow from pip (without the binary URL option) and latest numpy (Mac OS 10.12). TensorFlow version is 1.0.0, numpy is 1.12.0.